# Unmarshalling error in apache camel with jaxb data format

Tags: web-services, jaxb, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am completely new to **camel and jboss fuse** and I am facing one problem. I am trying to send a request to my webservice using **soapUI**.I have used **cxf component of apache camel and jaxb in apache camel**. In the request there is a tag AuthTimeStamp.

When I am entering

```
 <AuthTimestamp>2009-01-02T11:13:56.745+05:30 </AuthTimestamp>
```

it is working fine. But when I am entering:

```
 <AuthTimestamp>3-23-190017:00</AuthTimestamp>
```

it is giving me error. I believe jaxb is doing some kind of validation and my request is failing there. But I don't to return soap fault type error.

I want a proper xml to be returned with proper information. If the request passes to my cxf bean then I can handle the exception make a proper error packet and return it. Similar questions have been asked before but I was not able to find appropriate solution.

Initial part of my camel route:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

    <!-- Service for gateway is exposed. cxfEndpoint mentioned in EsangamBeanConfig.xml-->
    <!-- <to uri="bean:NSDGPortTypeImpl"/> -->
    <!-- <simple>${body.getIISMessage()}</simple>  -->
    <!--     <to uri="bean:iISMessageProcessorID?method=logTransaction(${body})"/>
     -->

    <!--Here goes IISMessageContext(body) -->
    <!--Here goes SubmitDocument(body) -->
    <!--Here goes IISMessageContext(body) -->

    <camelContext id="eSangamMessagingCamelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <dataFormats>
            <jaxb contextPath="in.gov.esangam.eservices.messaging" prettyPrint="true" encoding="UTF-8" id="myJaxb"/>
        </dataFormats>
        <route id="eSangam Messaging Start">
            <from uri="cxf:bean:NSDGPortType"/>
            <log message="New Request Arrived at Gateway"/>
```

Below is the stack trace:

```
14:47:31,842 | WARN  | qtp1545452967-60 | PhaseInterceptorChain            | 118 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-core - 3.0.4.redhat-620133 | Interceptor for {http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/schema/NSDG/wsdl}NSDGPortTypeService#{http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/schema/NSDG/wsdl}processSubmitDocument has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: 3/23/19005:00:00PM 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:908)[132:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:712)[132:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:176)[132:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:194)[131:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-wsdl:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307)[118:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)[118:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)[123:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)[123:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)[123:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)[123:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)[123:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)[123:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)[123:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)[89:org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:268)[123:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:503)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:69)[101:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:533)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:240)[101:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:75)[101:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:3.2.3]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate.jetty-all-server:8.1.17.v20150415]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: 3/23/19005:00:00PM
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 3/23/19005:00:00PM]]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:483)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:417)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:394)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.doUnmarshal(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:858)[132:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.access$100(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:102)[132:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder$2.run(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:897)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:895)[132:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:3.0.4.redhat-620133]
    ... 40 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: 3/23/19005:00:00PM
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 3/23/19005:00:00PM]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:740)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:770)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:766)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.handleParseConversionException(Loader.java:275)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyLoader.text(LeafPropertyLoader.java:69)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.text(UnmarshallingContext.java:589)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.processText(StAXStreamConnector.java:338)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleEndElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:216)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:185)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:415)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: 3/23/19005:00:00PM
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 3/23/19005:00:00PM]
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 3/23/19005:00:00PM
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parseYear(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)[:]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(Unknown Source)[:]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseDateTime(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:378)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$2.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:279)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$2.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:277)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.FilterTransducer.parse(FilterTransducer.java:84)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.parse(TransducedAccessor.java:245)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyLoader.text(LeafPropertyLoader.java:65)[113:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl:2.2.11.1]
    ... 51 more
14:47:31,846 | INFO  | qtp1545452967-60 | Soap12FaultOutInterceptor        | 134 - org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-soap - 3.0.4.redhat-620133 | class org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap12FaultOutInterceptor$Soap12FaultOutInterceptorInternalapplication/soap+xml
```

Comment: So what is the problem to send the acceptable format?

Comment: @Rao , Just incase if a client sends a unacceptable format I would want to send back a proper xml packet to convey the error rather then a soap fault. But the request is not entering in the route.

Comment: The log seems to say that the problem is that you are using an <authTimeStamp> element instead of <authTimestamp> element. Could you check that ?

Comment: @DimpreJean-Sébastien.. where exactly in logs did you find that. I am only able to find AuthTimestamp A,T,S capital and i am passing that only in my request.

Comment: @Asim Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/schema/NSDG/envelope", local:"AuthTimeStamp") => The element with A,T,S capital is unexpected. And Expected elements are <{http://www.mit.gov.in/eGov/schema/NSDG/envelope}AuthTimestamp>, ... => The element with Only A,T in capitals is in Expected Elements. Line 5-12 of the log you posted

Comment: @DimpreJean-Sébastien. yes you are right . But i am just changing the value inside the tag. For first value it is working fine and for second one it is not. So I don't think the problem is with the tag , it is same everytime but when i change the value it gives me this error.

Comment: @Asim I was just pointing that out since it's the error that's the log shows. While it is JAXB Schema validation that raises the error, it might be interesting to find why your XML ends up with an Over-capitalized tag when your timestamp is different.

Comment: @DimpreJean-Sébastien..sorry i messed up the logs. Initially i was passing AuthTimeStamp capital  hence it was showing that expected AuthTimestamp statement. After that i corrected AuthTimestamp but i didn't update the stacktrace here.Now i have updated it .The error is still the same.

Comment: @Asim The error come from the conversion from your AuthTimestamp element to XmlGregorianCalendar, which expect a correct lexicalRepresentation of a date. So your error does not come from validation but from the unmarshalling process itself. From there, i don't think i can help you further, i'm not familiar with the technology you're using. My hunch would be to use an XmlAdapter to handle the unmarshall of your element manually, but i don't know if it is actually possible in your case. I hope i've helped you, if only a little.